# SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess throws AccessControlException for existing system property

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have some thirdparty code, which uses `SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(...)` to check wether it can access a system property or not. This method throws an `AccessControlException` although I set the system property in appengine-web.xml and I can access the property through `System.getProperty(...)`. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Sandbox](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Sandbox) on app engine I'm guessing it is one of the disabled features given it's tossing an `AccessControlException`

Comment: this would be quite inconsistent behavior, because the `AccessControlException` says `access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission PROPERTY_NAME read)`, but the property is still accessible